# Angular component keeps refreshing on its own and I lose state

Tags: angular

I have a view in which part of it loads another within using routing. Here is the part that loads another:

```
<a href="/productDetails/{{product.ProductId}}">{{product.Name}}</a>
```

And here is the div where I have my other component (productDetails) getting loaded:

```
<div class='col-md-6 body-content'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

That works fine. But, whenever the component gets loaded, the hosting component refreshes itself and I lose its state. I don't know why this behaviour is happening because I coded the same app in AngularJS and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using routeLink attribute instead of href

```
<a [routerLink]="['/productDetails', product.ProductId]">{{product.Name}}</a>
```

Update your route defintion as

```
{path: 'productDetails/:ProductId', component: ProductDetailsComponent
```

Comment: When I do that only the first link from the list works. The other links show that they have the right route but when I click them they do nothing (i.e. the component doesn't get loaded).

Comment: you might have not configured the routeparams in your route definition

Comment: Route definition is fine because the first link with the parameter works. In any case, here is my route definition: {path: 'productDetails/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent}

Comment: still the same issue happening.

Comment: At least now it is not refreshing on its own, but links still don't work (except for the first one).

Comment: are you available in **team viewer**?

Comment: Not yet, I'll set it up and let you know. Thanks Aravind.

Comment: reach me out @ aravind2109